# Accessing Localhost from Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I currently have a PC running Visual Studio/IIS Express and I need to do some IE8 testing, which requires me to run a Hyper-V VM.

When I go into the Hyper-V VM, I can't seem to go to reach `http://localhost:portnumber`.

I guess I need to set up hosts for localhost, but I also can't seem to reach the IP address of the main PC either.

Can someone suggest some steps to follow to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: From within the VM, `localhost` is the VM, not the physical host machine... you'll need to configure the VM's networking correctly, and address the physical host by IP / hostname as if you were any other machine on the network.

Answer (score 0):

To access the host from the virtual machine you need to setup the virtual machine to use the correct network settings as well as updating the settings of you host system.

You can find a guide of how this might be done here:

[Debugging IIS Express website from a HyperV Virtual Machine](http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2014/11/24/debugging-iis-express-website-from-a-hyperv-virtual-machine/)

The guide describes the necessary steps. Hope it helps.